# Radon measures determined by value on compact subsets

Tags: measure-theory

My Professor states that Radon measure is determined by its value on compact subsets. It seems abstruse to me even with assumption that the space $G$ is locally compact.

I wonder whether that statement is correct.

Comment: Write down your definition of a  Radon measure .

Comment: Sorry for asking such a trivial question...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this is true, because Radon measures are inner regular.